# Ruby on Rails RSpec Error: Encoding::UndefinedConversionErrors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sqlite

I'm following along with Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#fig%3aheroku_app_31). I've completed the tutorial, but now when I try to run the command

```
bundle exec rspec spec/
```

I get a whole bunch of Encoding::UndefinedConversionErrors. Here's an example:

```
 101) Authentication AuthenticationPages signin with valid information followed by signout 
   Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
   ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xDC" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "remember_token", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
   # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:34:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've searched similar problems on Stack Overflow, but the problems involved file I/O, so the solutions there didn't really apply to my problem. I've done some reading of the test.log file after running rspec, and I got a hint that it could have something to do with the way my data is being uploaded to the server, some kind of weird conversion error going on there.

Here is what I have in database.yml to define my test database:

```
test:
adapter: sqlite3
database: db/test.sqlite3
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
encoding: UTF8
```

I'm running Rails 4.0.0, Ruby 2.0.0 and using an sqlite3 database. The sqlite gem I have in my Gemfile is: `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'`. The gem in my Gemfile for rspec is the following: `gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'`.

Essentially, I'm trying to figure out why these errors are occurring and how to make them stop happening, and I'm not really sure about either.

EDIT: Here are the contents of my factories.rb file:

```
#encoding: utf-8

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "Person #{n}" }
  sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }
  password "foobar"
  password_confirmation"foobar"

  factory :admin do
   admin true
  end
 end

 factory :micropost do
  content "Lorem ipsum"
  user
 end
end
```

I've also noticed that my development.sqlite3 and test.sqlite3 had some ASCII characters in it. Using Notepad++, I tried to re-encode the documents as UTF-8, but then I got an error that required I reset and re-migrate my database. After I did all that, the development and test SQLITE3 files were back to containing ASCII characters. I'm not sure if that could have something to do with it.

Comment: What changed in your environment since you last successfully ran the tests?

Comment: Not sure how much this'll help, but here's a comparison between two Git branches, the one, 'sign-up' was the last branch that the tests worked. The new one, 'sing-in-out', was when things stopped working.

https://github.com/taro-tsujimoto/sample-app/compare/sign-up...sign-in-out

Other than that, not much changed in my development environment that I'm aware of.

Comment: It looks like you added the bootstrap gem. Did other gems change as a result of this (or for any other reason)?

Comment: What do you mean by your database "having characters in it". Are you referring to the contents of some existing records in the database? If so, how did the characters reappear in the test database after you "reset" it? Are you running some task to pre-populate the databases? Also, how is "editing a document" related to the database?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you're trying to put ASCII-8BIT character to UTF-8 encoded database. Did you change something in you user factory file? Any special characters eg. 'Ü' are there? Try to put on top of your factory file:

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

Comment: I edited my question to include the contents of my factories.rb file